# Loop through options

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have an WPF app which displays some data, and changes its units from, say, 'x' -> 'y' -> 'z' -> 'x' whenever a user click on it. What's the best possible way to achieve this?

p.s.: I've seen questions about loops here, using `foreach`, but they don't go back to the first option whenever the list ends.

Comment: Maybe show a bit of code? What kind of application are you working with (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by "units"? Is the data something like distance and clicking (something) changes it from 'meters'->'feet'->'inches'->'meters'?

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: As far as the looping goes, couldn't you check to see if you're at the last item on a click and then go to the first one? I can't tell if this is a very complex question or a very simple one...

Comment: Are you attempting to have an app "state"? I would use an `enum` to hold the app state, and increment through that. Once you get to the last item in the enum, circle back to the first.

Comment: @Dynguss Yep, it changes from Kms -> Miles -> Knots -> Kms.

Comment: @DaveZych Can you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `enum` to hold the units.

```
public enum Units
{
    Kms,
    Miles,
    Knots
}
```

Have a property holding the current units

```
public Units CurrentUnit { get; set; }
```

Then when the user clicks the button, cycle through the units to get the next one.

```
if (CurrentUnit == Enum.GetValues(typeof(Unit)).Cast<Unit>().Last())
{
    CurrentUnit = Unit.km;
}
else
{
    CurrentUnit = (Unit) (int) CurrentUnit + 1;
}
```

There's probably a better way to cycle the values but I can't think of one right now. This will do it though.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through a collection and return to the start by keeping the collection as well as a current location.  For example, using these values:

```
int currentUnit = 0;
List<string> units = new List<string>() { "x", "y", "z" };
```

You can "loop" through this in a "click" via something like:

```
string GetNextUnit()\
{
    if (++currentUnit == units.Count) current = 0;
    return units[currentUnit];
}
```